# Apache gives "forbidden" if the client's IP address is IPv6

Tags: apache2

[sorry, not even sure if my question makes sense].

Some users of my website have been complaining that they are getting "Forbidden" apache error.

After looking everywhere, I think the error is appearing whenever the requested user's IP address is IPv6.

I tested this by using the tool "www.browserling.com". Each time I got the error, I checked the IP address of the machine and when it was IPv6, I get this "Forbidden" error.

What do I have to do to resolve this?

Comment: Enable IPv6 networking, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the Apache configuration the VirtualHost directive for your website either doesn't use IP addresses, like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

or includes your IPv6 addresses, too, like:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.178.50:80 [fe80::219:99ff:fe6c:74a5]:80>
```